# python cgi won't load next

Tags: python, apache, shell, cgi

I wrote a cgi script that will open a firefox window using `os.system("firefox &")`.

So the idea is that it'll make a firefox window for me, and then print a confirmation page for the remote user.

The problem is that it only prints the confirmation page after I close the firefox window. This is especially puzzling because if I run the script in terminal as opposed to letting apache run it, it prints the confirmation html right away like it is supposed to.

Can anyone offer any insight as to why I am having trouble loading the confirmation page immediately?

Comment: why would you want a CGI script to open windows on the server, anyway?

Comment: I am trying to make my android a remote control

Comment: i understand this is a giant security hazard, but it's my htpc which has no sensitive material on it

Answer (score 0):

don't use `os.system`. Use [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess).

[`os.system` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.system) says:

> *The subprocess module provides more powerful facilities for spawning
>   new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is
>   preferable to using this function.*

Try this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['firefox'])
```

Comment: Now I have:  `subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '-u', 'userwithpermissions', '/home/script/to/set/envvars/','/usr/lib/firefox-10.0/firefox --display=:0.0 &', '&'])`.

problem remains -- it opens firefox fine on the server, but the client only can half-load the next page. as soon as i close the firefox window, it loads the rest of the client's confirmation page.

Comment: My guess would be that apache is keeping the CGI process alive while there are living subprocesses and thus not sending the whole response to the client.

Comment: That would make sense. do you think mod_wsgi, mod_python, or mod_fastcgi would help?

Comment: or maybe i can spoof the exit status of firefox?